# SpriteKit SKLightNode falloff property has no effect

Tags: ios, swift

I've been trying out the `SKLightNode` feature of SpriteKit and I'm having trouble manipulating shadows. Specifically, it appears the the `falloff` property of my `SKLightNode` doesn't do anything no matter what I set it to. Here is my code for the light:

```
//set up lights
var light = SKLightNode()
light.categoryBitMask = LightCategory.Light1
/*THIS DOESN'T DO ANYTHING*/ light.falloff = CGFloat(0.01)
light.ambientColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
light.lightColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.5)
light.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.25, blue: 0.25, alpha: 0.5)
light.position = CGPointMake(size.width / 2.0, size.height * 0.75)
light.zPosition = DrawOrder.Lights
addChild(light)
```

And here is where I add it to the player:

```
//set up player
player.position = CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.1, y: size.height * 0.3)
player.shadowCastBitMask = LightCategory.Light1
player.zPosition = DrawOrder.Sprites
addChild(player)
```

[According to Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKLightNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKLightNode/falloff), `falloff` is supposed to set "the exponent for the rate of decay of the light source" and accepts a `CGFloat` from 0.0 to 1.0. But no matter what I set `falloff` to, the shadow is endless.

What am I doing wrong?

Updated with screenshot (FPS low due to simulator):

[image: screenshot showing the issue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this problem before. As a work-around you can just set the `falloff` to a number larger than 1. In fact, if you create an `SKLightNode` in your `SKScene`'s `.sks` file, it has a `falloff` of `1.5` by default so perhaps the documentation is incorrect?

---

**Edit**

In your case your problem also seems to be you've set the `ambientColor` to white. Set it to black and you'll be able to see the light working properly.

Comment: Just tested this. I can put literally any numeric value into .falloff without getting errors, even negative numbers. Still, nothing has any effect.

Comment: Interesting! Setting `ambientColor` to `blackColor` does make the background lighting change, but not the shadow on the player (still goes on for infinity). Also, values from 0.0 to 1.0 have no effect on `falloff`, but values 2.0 - 5.0 do. At 5.0, the light goes completely dark.

Comment: What do you mean 'goes on for infinity'? I'm getting the same results with regard to fall off. Possibly a bug with SpriteKit.

Comment: I updated my original post with a screenshot. I also noticed that `SKSpriteNodes` have a `shadowCastBitmask` (shown in the image) and a `shadowedBitmask` (which I tested achieving no results). What I don't understand now is why the shadow doesn't change length based on `falloff`.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I'm pretty sure it's currently not possible to have shadows that don't extend forever using Sprite-Kit... Regarding using `shadowCastBitmask` and `shadowedBitmask`, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28662600/sklightnode-cast-shadow-issue/29821325#29821325

Comment: Ah, thank you. Looks like I'm just going to be better off making a drop shadow effect manually.

Comment: Glad I could help. Sprite-Kit is still pretty new so hopefully these are things Apple intend to add in the future. Good luck with your project!