# Spritekit SKLightNode : light collision detection

Tags: sprite-kit, sklightnode

My question is how to detect if any of sprites in the scene is affected by light node.

Didn`t found anything related to this issue.
Is there some delegate method like didBeginContact for SKLightNode?

Answer (score 3):

When you create a [SKLightNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKLightNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKLightNode/categoryBitMask) you set its `categoryBitMask` just as you would with physics bodies.

[SKSpriteNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKSpriteNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKSpriteNode/lightingBitMask) has a `lightingBitMask` property which you can set to determine whether this sprite is lit by a light node or not.

SKSpriteNode has additional properties regarding SKLightNode such as `shadowCastBitMask` and `shadowedBitMask` which deal with the sprite casting a shadow and being hidden inside a shadow.

Be aware though that the SKLightNode currently has a confirmed bug. Look at this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28662600/sklightnode-cast-shadow-issue) for more information.